# re-arrange task for minimal execution time

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, optimization

Working on below task re-arrange problem, post problem and my code in Python 2.7. My specific questions,

1. Any better ideas to optimize for algorithm time complexity (or space complexity)?
2. When we find a task cannot be arranged (means separate by another different task, so that no additional wait time), my current implementation is to put such tasks in any free slots (refer to loop of `while counter < f`), and I am wondering if what I should do is (1) put the remaining un-arranged task/frequency back into heap, and (2) find next high frequency task to process?

For bulletin point 2, I tested my code is ok (ok means my code returns minimal execution time plus wait time), but if there are any bugs and I should do (1) and (2) other than my current implementation, please feel free to point out.

**Problem**

Given a set of tasks like [A, A, B], and int k, which is the waiting time between two same tasks. Calculate the min total execution time if you are allowed to rearrange the tasks. Assume the execution for each individual task is 1.

In above example
A A B, k = 1, without rearrangement, the execution time would be 4:

```
A wait A B

1  1   1 1
```

with rearrangement, the execution time would be 3:

```
A B A

1 1 1
```

**Source code**,

```
from collections import defaultdict
import heapq


def rearrange_tasks(tasks):
    freq = defaultdict(int)
    for t in tasks:
        freq[t] += 1
    h = []
    heapq.heapify(h)
    result = [0] * len(tasks)
    for t,f in freq.items():
        heapq.heappush(h, (-f, t))
    while len(h) > 0:
        f, t = heapq.heappop(h)
        f = -f
        write_index = 0
        while write_index < len(result) and result[write_index] != 0:
            write_index += 1
        counter = 0
        while write_index < len(result) and counter < f:
            result[write_index] = t
            write_index += 2
            counter += 1
        # write tasks which have to be consecutive
        write_index = 0
        while counter < f:
            if result[write_index] != 0:
                write_index += 1
            else:
                result[write_index] = t
                write_index += 1
                counter += 1
    return result


def calculate_execution_time(tasks, k):
    exec_time = 0
    for i, t in enumerate(tasks):
        if i == 0:
            exec_time += 1
            continue
        if t == tasks[i-1]:
            exec_time += k
            exec_time += 1
        else:
            exec_time += 1
    return exec_time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tasks = ['A', 'A', 'B']
    result = rearrange_tasks(tasks)
    print result
    print calculate_execution_time(result, 1)

    tasks = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'B', 'B', 'B']
    result = rearrange_tasks(tasks)
    print result
    print calculate_execution_time(result, 1)
```

**Edit 1**:

fix out of index error by using condition `while write_index < len(result) and counter < f:`, other than condition `counter < f:`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you code throws an error on some inputs. For example, I tried this one:

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']

...
  File "orig.py", line 22, in rearrange_tasks
    result[write_index] = t
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Here are some suggested changes. They are focused less on optimizing for speed and more on algorithm clarity. I'm somewhat skeptical that you should worry too much about speed -- how large are your inputs and how many distinct task values are there? This algorithm seems mostly linear, especially if the number of distinct task values is small.

```
from collections import Counter
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush

def rearrange_tasks(tasks):

    # Make a heap of (-FREQ, TASK) tuples.
    freq = Counter(tasks)
    h = [(-f, t) for t, f in freq.items()]
    heapify(h)

    result = []
    prev = None
    while h:
        # Get the most frequent item.
        f, t = heappop(h)

        # If it is a repeat and if there are other items,
        # put it back and grab 2nd most frequent item instead.
        if t == prev and h:
            item = (f, t)
            f, t = heappop(h)
            heappush(h, item)

        # Put selected item back on heap, after adjusting frequency.
        if f < -1:
            heappush(h, ((f + 1), t))

        # Add task to the result.
        result.append(t)
        prev = t

    return result

def calculate_execution_time(tasks, k):
    n = 0
    prev = None
    for t in tasks:
        n += 1 + int(t == prev) * k
        prev = t
    return n

def run(tasks):
    result = rearrange_tasks(tasks)
    assert Counter(tasks) == Counter(result)
    print
    print 'len    =', len(tasks)
    print 'time   =', calculate_execution_time(result, 1)
    print 'result =', ''.join(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run('AAB')
    run('AABCCCCCCCC')
    run('AAAACDEEBBB')
    run('AAAACDEEBBBBBBBBBBBB')
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice FMc, and vote up. I have fixed my code issue, see edit 1 section for details. Your algorithm always process one letter, than put it back and try to fetch the next highest frequency task, my algorithm will process highest frequency task, then 2nd highest frequency task, etc. Do you think my logic have any logical bugs comparing to yours?